# Why do we take $\langle{v^2}\rangle = \langle{v}\rangle^2$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, speed

In Ashcroft and Mermin's Chapter 1, the equipartition theorem is often used to evaluate the mean speed of an electron in an (ideal) electron gas treated with classical statistical mechanics. That is, it is often written that
$$ \langle{v}\rangle = \sqrt{3kT/m}.$$
However, strictly speaking, equipartition of energy tells us that
$$ \sqrt{\langle{v^2}\rangle} = \sqrt{3kT/m}$$
which is not the same thing.Thus there must surely be some appeal to the large ensemble of electrons in writing $\langle{v^2}\rangle = \langle{v}\rangle^2$; my question is what justification in particular is used?

Comment: Well in an ideal gas $\langle v\rangle=0$. Did you mean $\langle |v|\rangle$. I'm not sure exactly where this statement comes from - is it possible this was just meant as an order of magnitude statement for a back of the envelope estimate of something?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, I am using boldface to denote vectors so that $|\textbf{v}| \equiv v$ as a matter of notation. And yes, this is used as a back of the envelope calculation leading to, e.g., the specific heat of the electron gas. @AndrewChristensen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. This is not the correct value for $\langle v\rangle$. [It's a classic problem (link)](https://physicstasks.eu/2174/the-most-probable,-average-and-root-mean-square-speed-of-gas-molecules#:%7E:text=The%20magnitude%20of%20the%20most,3RTMm.) to find the rms velocity, most likely velocity $v_{\text{ML}}$, and mean velocity of a Maxwell Boltzmann distribution. Of course they're all proportional to the dimensional analysis answer:
$$
v_0=\sqrt{\frac{k_B T}{m}}
$$
But their specific values are (using the same notation as the question where $v=|\mathbf{v}|$)
$$
\langle v\rangle=\sqrt{8/\pi}v_0
$$
$$
\sqrt{\langle v^2\rangle}=\sqrt{3}v_0
$$
$$
v_{\text{ML}}=\sqrt{2}v_0
$$
For an order of magnitude, or back of the envelope estimate, any or all of these are fine choices - as long as you don't expect to get a precisely accurate answer. It's worth noting, however, that the RMS value is most likely to show up in any calculation, since at least it treats vectors and probability distributions properly ($|\mathbf{v}|^2$ is an analytic function of $v_x$,$v_y$,$v_z$; and an expectation value is a reasonable thing to do with a distribution). So often by using the $\sqrt{\langle v^2\rangle}$ value you actually arrive at the exactly correct answer even though you're only doing an order of magnitude estimate.

Answer (score 2):

The proper result is
$$
   \frac{1}{2}m\langle v^2\rangle =\frac{3}{2}kT
   \Rightarrow
   \langle v^2\rangle = \frac{3kT}{m}
$$
The square-root of $\langle v^2\rangle$ is the velocity of a particle with the mean kinetic energy, and in this sense, it is the representative velocity of a typical particle.  Obviously it doesn't make sense to use $\langle v\rangle$ as the representative velocity because it is zero.